# ajax post success but php reply Undefined array key "id"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

front-end code

```
var data = params[0].data[0];
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'image.php',
  data: {
    id: data,
  },
  async: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Backend:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

I'm try to use `var_dump($_POST['id']);` go to search but  reply  is NULL
console.log(data) have information ,
var_dump($_POST);  reply array(0) { },
payload have id key is id:123 but image reply Undefined array key "id" is xhr

Comment: I have to say this doesn't make sense, the code you've got for sending the data seems to be correct. Are you sure that the output you're seeing in the Console is the output for this exact request? The next thing to do is to look in the Network tool in the browser to look at the request, you can click on the request to image.php when it appears, and then view the payload (to see exactly what was sent), the response to see exactly what was returned, and you can check it was definitely an ajax/xhr request.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a

```
console.log(data)
```

statement to verify that the data variable holds the expected value. Make sure that params[0].data[0] is not undefined or null.
Ensure that the PHP code in image.php is correct and doesn't contain any issues.

Comment: Regardless what the value of `params[0].data[0]` is in JS, or if it even exists or not, if the request gets sent, the `id` parameter should still exist in the posted data in PHP since it's hard coded. The value wouldn't be set, but the key would exist. Side note: It's great that you want to help out (keep it up), but this isn't really an answer as much as a debugging suggestion that might or might not give them some valuable info. That should rather have been a comment. Answers should be clear solutions.